# Crystal Report - Displaying field with no values

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report built in Crystal Reports 2013 where I want to show the sum of all transactions during the month for a group of projects and a list of accounts for each project, including if there were none. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSFed.jpg)

```
I have used the IsNull when trying to pull the data:
    {gl_trans.Yr} = #### and {gl_trans.Prd} = ## and
    {gl_trans.project-no} in [list of project] and
    (IsNull({gl_trans.Gl-code}) or {gl_trans.Gl-code} in [list of accounts])
```

but I am only returned data for GL-codes that have transactions. I know I am missing something but after two days can't figure out what it is.

Comment: What is the purpose of using the isnull in pulling data

Comment: It is suppose to test for null or blank values. Example of usage is at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/17675-crystal-reports-using-blank-or-null